# Potential bug in Android Wear SensorManager?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors

I have two fragments, fragment A and fragment B. Fragment A uses a shaking gesture to switch to fragment B, and fragment B uses a different gesture to switch back to fragment A. So when I'm in fragment A, I register gesture A with the SensorManager, and when a shake is detected, I unregister gesture A, switch to fragment B, and register gesture B with the SensorManager.

Fragment A:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    private MainWearActivity mMainWearActivity;
    private SensorManager mSensorMgr;
    private GestureA gestureA;
    private OnShakeListener gestureAListener;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMainWearActivity = (MainWearActivity) getActivity();
        mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) mMainWearActivity.getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        gestureA = new GestureA();
        gestureAListener = new OnShakeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                gestureADetected();
            }
        };
        gestureA.setOnShakeListener(gestureAListener);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        stopListening();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void gestureADetected(){
        mMainWearActivity.replaceFragment(mMainWearActivity.getFrag("B"));
    }

    private void startListening(){
        mMainWearActivity.registerListener(gestureA);
    }

    private void stopListening(){
        mMainWearActivity.unregisterListener(gestureA);
    }
}
```

Fragment B:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    private MainWearActivity mMainWearActivity;
    private FragmentManager fm;
    private SensorManager mSensorMgr;
    private GestureB gestureB;
    private OnShakeListener gestureBListener;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMainWearActivity = (MainWearActivity) getActivity();
        fm = mMainWearActivity.getFragmentManager();
        mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) mMainWearActivity.getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        gestureB = new GestureB();
        gestureBListener = new OnShakeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                gestureBDetected();
            }
        };
        gestureB.setOnShakeListener(gestureBListener);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        stopListening();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void gestureBDetected(){
        fm.popBackStackImmediate();
    }

    private void startListening(){
        mMainWearActivity.registerListener(gestureB);
    }

    private void stopListening(){
        mMainWearActivity.unregisterListener(gestureB);
    }
}
```

If I run this app, and continuously switch between fragment A and fragment B, after a few times the SensorManager stops detecting gestures. This is not the case on an Android phone where this setup works fine.

This is just a small test app I made to check whether the behaviour could be replicated, but my actual app is much larger and with many more gestures, so simply registering all the gestures once with the SensorManager and checking for the different fragments/gestures is not an ideal solution as it becomes very messy and complicated. Does anyone know of a way to "clean" the SensorManager so that it loses all references to any previously registered/unregistered listeners? Or is this just a bug in Android Wear. The device I'm using is a Moto360. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered refactoring your code to use State Pattern or Command Pattern, since a lot of your code seems to be redundant and your problem may be well hidden and hard to trace ?

Comment: I may end up having to use a State Pattern, however, it would be much simpler to just register and unregister the listeners. It works fine on an Android phone with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

In your questions of recent days, which contain similar code and I presume are related, I have not seen a posting of the code for your event-listener/gesture-detectors.  It appears that at least one of them uses the gyro sensor.  In one posted version of your code you were using a fast update rate (SENSOR_DELAY_GAME).

Is there logic in your listening/detection processing to ensure that a given wrist motion only causes the gesture to be reported once?  I'm thinking about the control flow in your design: sensor event, gesture detection, fragment transaction, listener unregister.  Because all this is happening on the main thread, and the fragment events are asynchronous, I suspect your listener will get a few more events after the one that triggered the gesture detection.  This is more likely with a faster update rate.  In my experience, the execution of the steps involved in a fragment transaction, along with the fragment callbacks (`onCreateView()`, `onResume()`, etc.), can take 20 milliseconds or more.  Until `onPause()` for the fragment being removed is called, the listener for that fragment is still registered and events are being queued for the listener.  If multiple gesture detections are fired, your fragment management could get messed up, perhaps causing the same fragment to be added multiple times.  Adding `Log` statements to your `gestureXDetected()` would confirm that the gestures are being detected once, as your design expects.

To your question about a bug in the `SensorManager`, well, anything is possible, but I think it's very unlikely.  You could easily confirm your suspicion by putting debug code in the `onCreate()` method of your MainActivity to reg/unreg a listener 100 times before starting normal operation, then observe if your app is immediately sluggish or the delays develop after you switch fragments repeatedly.